# use case for finding foreign key with a trigger or function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Sample Code:
https://gist.github.com/telagraphic/be35fd3506f912c7a91c

I have a trigger that is throwing a data type constraint on a column.
Makes sense as to why it is throwing the error, but I thought the trigger would update the value before it gets inserted.

I have found an alternate solution of using a function in the insert to retrieve the foreign key.

My question is it possible to use a trigger to find and insert the foreign key?  Or is a function the preferred method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you are trying to populate the category field for the INSERT into EXPENSES table, based on the ID from the CATEGORIES table using the Category name.

If I understand this right, then you should use the function in your solution and not the trigger. Triggers only get invoked or fired, when a DML statement (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) is executed on a table - in this case the CATEGORIES table. Since you are inserting into the EXPENSES table, the trigger on the CATEGORIES table will not be invoked.

Also, typically you generally use triggers on parent tables in a relation to update/populate the child tables in that relation. I think in your case you are trying to do the reverse, since it seems EXPENSES is a child of CATEGORIES on the CATEGORY_ID field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify.  It's a one to one relationship between the two tables.  The parent to child relationship helps explain why to use a trigger.